# How to add swipe feature to a image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image gallery and I want to add swipe feature to it,next and prev big image. I don't want to use any pluggin. I have some code, I tried some but I was unable to make it work. Any advice is highly appreciated.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){
 $("img").on("swipeleft",function(){
    console.log("Left");
  }); 

 $("img").on("swiperight",function(){
    console.log("Right");
  });
```

});

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqqqbqaz/)

Thanks!

Comment: your jsfiddle goes to www.example.com

Comment: done. I didn't saw it...

Comment: You'll need to define your two events, `swipeleft` and `swiperight` and trigger those events based on a sequence of `touchevents` (`touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend`). The `duration`, `velocity`, and `direction` will determine if it's a "swipe" and the direction. If you need help with the logic, a simple `swipe` event can be found here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml

Comment: You should just get a jquery plugin for this, it is still js/jquery. If you define your own, you can still call it a plugin. I think you misunderstand what a plugin really is.

Answer (score -1):

the `swipeleft` event listener is not available with only jQuery. You can use jQuery Mobile, or craft your own using the `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend`. Assuming you only want to execute something once, the following code should do:

```
var swiping = false;

$('#div').on('touchmove', function (event) {
  swiping = true;
})


$('#div').on('touchstart', function (event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ( swiping = true ) {
      console.log('swiping');
    }
  }, 50)
})
```

The `setTimeout` likely isn't necessary since `touchmove` begins at the same time as `touchstart` - but I left it there in case any given browser performs differently.